# How to secure a price passed to a payment gateway on client?

Tags: javascript, client-side, payment-gateway

Using `Javascript`, say a customer buy a product that cost 10$.

Many payment gateways, like PayPal and Stripe, offer a client side `Form` where you input the sale data (price, amount, buyer address, etc), and it's being sent to the gateway (e.g PayPal) **from the client side**.

But, at this point when i fill the form using `Javascript` **on the client side**, someone can change the price from 10 to 1 and pay only 1 to PayPal.

**I know things has to be validated on my server**, but validation means that the server is sending back to client a response saying this price is good or not good, **but this respond can also be manipulated**.

So how is it that companies allow client side payment anyway using a form ?
How/where the actual sale data is being passed to the payment gateway ? client? server?

Comment: You don't make the client send the price. Similarly you don't validate that the Paypal transaction was successful by asking the client if it was.

Comment: You can make also set the price in the client, if before the confirmation you check the server and the amount. Of course this assumes there is something similar a unique ID for the order and/or item the user is going to buy previously registered in the server and connected to the actual payment made from the client.

Comment: Rule #1:  never trust the client side, Rule #2 never trust the client side...

Comment: @CONvid19 thanks but that wasn't the question, i know people like to repeat this rule but it's being already said many times :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Add a complete process example.

(it can be done in several way this is just one way an example to show the process)

The user arrive to your website and want to buy an item. This item must have a record in your database, with a unique ID.

When the user click the "buy" button the server prepare a payment request, and store it in the database with the unique ID of the product as reference for the price, or even the price it self.

So now you have something like a "token" related to the payment that the user need to make.

After this you prepare the form with the server asking the user ro pay, you redirect the user with the client...

Than you check the payment status with the server, checking fit with the unique token you set in the beginning. And here if everithyng is fine you send from the server to the client the confirmation of payment recived and only now you set that "**the sale has been made**".

[Never trust the client](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11583008) is the normal advice to follow in this case. Sure the payment input can be manipulated in the client side.

But you will need to check the input in the server anyway.

To confirm a payment with PayPal and Stripe you only have to do it in the server side. So basically the client is just the input that make the process start.

After that the user need to make the payment, and then you need to verify the payment in the server, and for this normally you associate a unique ID to the payment that refer to the order in your DB so you know the right price for that item, and you can verify on the server.

As an example here Stripe show a picture of the process:
[image]

Comment: I don't agree with "you only have to do it on server side" Both Stripe and Paypal allow doing it on the client side, the whole point of Stripe was 7 lines of code of Javascript where you provide the card number and price. Also, how is it that paypal provide you a way to use a Form on client side with url "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" , and IPN, where i fill this form on client and then redirected to a Paypal page using this form's details ? There is clearly a way to send the sale data from client, because this is how most API works.

Comment: You can start on the client. But you can't verify the payment in the client. Stripe and PayPal API work like this. I use Stripe and PayPal several time. You can start the payment with JavaScript in the client, but if you don't check the payment status with the server you will never know if the payment is confirmed or not. When, in your software, you need to verify a payment with Stripe or PayPal you must do it in the server side. There is no way in the client only to check for it and be sure that it is not been manipulated.

Comment: did you ever tried to do it ? once you start the payment from the client it means you already provide the sale detials to paypal, redirected to their page, pay, and get a payment confirmation to the server. At this point, the payer and receiver already get a confirmation ( can be for a wrong/hacked price), so at this point how is it matter if i check in my server if the payment was ok? all sides including paypal already confirmed a payment using a wrong price that came from the client.

Comment: Yes I did several time. Basic idea is that you have a unique ID saved in your DB connected to the payment process. So you know the price before the client will make the payment.

Comment: so if i know the price before, how to i check it ? with an if statement on client ? this can be manipulated. Asking the server? his respond to client can also be manipulated. At some point, there is a variable that goes OUT from the client to paypal with price data, and it can be tempered with. I simply don't understand how exactly you guard you price.

Comment: You MUST check it on the server, you can't check anything like this in the client.

As @mti2935 point out, for example the PayPal doc is clear, you need to check it in the server: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/ipn/IPNImplementation/

Comment: thanks, but you keep saying the same mantra, and its not helpful because " check it on the server" is nice, question is when. With Paypal IPN, your server get a payment confirmation (! !) which mean at this point the sale has been made. so who "check with the server" ? the client ? how ? any server respond can be changed. Do you understand that when paypal call my server its already when a sale has been made ? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/ipn/IPNIntro/#ipn-protocol-and-architecture

Comment: The problem is that "the sale has been made" you need to write your software in a way that "the sale has been made" only after the server validate the payment, and you need to start the process from the server too. I will update my main response so you can have a more details explanation.

Comment: take a look at my main resposne now is updated with an example of how you need to set up the all process, if any things is unclear just ask I will update it.

Comment: thank you for the help, paypal have their own protocol and it can't be change.

Comment: Also with Stripe and with any other payment services you will need to use the server, with client only you have no way to verify not only the amount but also the confirmation. Also the confirmation it self can be fake with client only verification...

Comment: thanks, as i said, i know i have to confirm with the server, quesion is when i have the opportunity. I am reading more and will update ! thanks ! :)

Comment: Note that it is unnecessary for bad actors to receive errors in real time.  If necessary for implementation reasons, it's OK to tell users "your order has been processed" and then send a "your order was cancelled" e-mail a day later.

Answer (score 2):

This is the reason that Paypal has the IPN.  One of the values sent in the IPN message from Paypal to your server is the transaction amount.  If the client were to manipulate the transaction amount the way that you described, you would be able to detect this in your IPN listener script, and cancel the order.  See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/ipn/IPNImplementation/ for more info.

Comment: thanks, i read this document 100 times :) the thing is that the IPN is sending a transaction body to my server, and i need to replay fast with the exact same body. BUT - paypal say - do not go to your db at this moment - just answer the IPN, also they even don't provide a way to reject this IPN, which imply (to me) that the reason for the IPN is not for me to validate data, but to them to validate my server.

Comment: "Consequently, your listener must not perform time-consuming operations (such as updating a database) before responding to an IPN."  - Which mean they don't expect you to validate data at this point with your DB - which indeed takes time. No ?

Comment: What that means is that your script should reply to the IPN message first, then query your database, perform the validation, etc.  If the amount in the IPN message is not what it should be, then your script should cancel the order.  There is no way for the client to manipulate the IPN message, because the message is sent directly from Paypal to your server.

Comment: but still, when you get an IPN it means the sale has been made.

Comment: No.  Don't finalize the sale until you receive the IPN notification, and the amount is as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You don't send the request from the client to PayPal. You send the request to your server, and your server sends the request to PayPal.

Never ever trust the client. It's trivial to change the data from the client. The price you show the client is only informative, the authoritative price is from your server.

It's like a grocery store: the price tag is informative. When the item is scanned at the counter, the price comes from the system, not the item. Same here: the client will send you the item, and the quantity. The server calculates the price (and checks if the quantity makes sense) and creates the request to PayPal.

Comment: This is just wrong. i don't understand how people say this. I just tried, Paypal provide a form for the client where you fill in the sale details, redirected to a paypal page, pay, then they will send a confirmation using IPN to my server. But the form data is being sent FROM THE CLIENT using this form action "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" and using "cmd":"_xclick".  I am not sure what am i missing here.

Comment: Check the [Paypal Integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/server-integration/#how-a-server-integration-works) documentation. It shows you how.

Comment: You can send the request of payment from the client, but you always need to verify it only in the server.

Comment: there is no room for vefitication, once its being sent to PayPal, with the form, it means you are redirected to their page USING THIS SALE DATA, put credit card, pay, ONLY THEN your server get a notification on a successful sale ( when its too late to validate). so i am not sure where exactly can you validate the sale.

Comment: @paulseems: if the price from the IPN doesn't match what it should, you would simply pass the user an error message like "we're having trouble confirming your payment", and ignore the payment. You can then manually reconcile (cancel) those charges.

Comment: "if the price from the IPN doesn't match"  - the IPN tell your server that A SALE HAS BEEN MADE". So how is it helpful to check something now ?